# Tried to restore xcode 5 project from backup and now get a fatal error

Tags: ios, xcode

Tried to restore xcode 5 project from backup because something I added to the app wasn't working and now get a fatal error.

I have no idea how to fix this, first I got this msg:

fatal error: file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/Mallory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/29VIL2542Q0C1/UIKit.pcm' was built
note: after modifying system headers, please delete the module cache at '/Users/Mallory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/29VIL2542Q0C1'
1 error generated.

I tried to fix the UIViewController.h file (I had changed the permissions of it before so changed them back) and renamed Module cache (instead of deleting it, just in case). Then I got this error:

fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file: 'Unable to load module "/Users/Mallory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/29VIL2542Q0C1/Darwin.pcm": file not found'
note: after modifying system headers, please delete the module cache at '/Users/Mallory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/29VIL2542Q0C1'
1 error generated.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: clean and rebuild? also make sure nothing in your build process messes with the PCH.

Comment: Time capsule is a life saver. I have time capsule backing up as much as possible, so when I do something silly I can just go restore to the folder were the project is saved and undo whatever I just did. I've done this with both xcode and eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

I would try to:

- Clean the project
- Touch the project's .pch file
- Perform a deep clean (Option+Command+Shift+K)
- iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings

I would also try to delete the module cache in /var/folders, here is a neat [ruby script](https://gist.github.com/orkoden/7010433) for clearing both that and derived data:

```
derivedDataFolder = Dir.glob(Dir.home + "/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*")
moduleCache = Dir.glob("/var/folders/**/com.apple.DeveloperTools*")
FileUtils.rm_rf derivedDataFolder + moduleCache
```

If it still does not work, a reinstall of Xcode could do the trick.

Comment: usually Product -> Clean and removing DerivedData helps with this issue.

Comment: @art-divin I agree. The reason for mentioning a few other possible things to try out is because he has already cleared DerivedData and I assume that he has tried a clean and rebuild already.